# Integrating native system libraries with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

What is a good way to integrate various SBT tasks with native libraries (for example, those from [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/), [LWGL](http://lwjgl.org/), or [JCuda](http://www.jcuda.de/)? Specifically,

1. Is there a recommended way to include a native library in the `run` task? A discussion on the SBT mailing list suggests these possibilities:

   - [Modify `JavaOptions`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/o1iGaMi4UeU/uKDWYBP7TPAJ) to include `-Djava.library.path=<path to native libraries>`, and then modify the `run` task to fork the JVM. (See [this plugin](https://github.com/philcali/sbt-lwjgl-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/LWJGLPlugin.scala) for an example.)
   - [Use the SBT `initialize` setting](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/o1iGaMi4UeU/lqp1YFtI-AUJ) to run code that calls `System.setProperty(...)` to configure `java.library.path`. Again, `run` must fork.
   - [Put the native libraries on the classpath](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/o1iGaMi4UeU/lhMsctSyt5QJ) before launching SBT.

   The last one has the advantage that `run` need not fork, but the disadvantage that the configuration must be done outside SBT.
2. Can I automatically include native libraries in the Eclipse project generated by the [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) plugin? It's possible to [rewrite the `.project` file in a post-processing step.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/lLOOyAzp3fY/ar0xEU1lilAJ) Is there example code? Is there a better way?
3. Can native libraries be included in the runnable Jar that is generated by a plugin such as [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), [sbt-onejar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar) or [sbt-proguard](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-proguard-plugin)?

I assume there is no direct SBT setting for native libraries. If something like that existed, could the above tasks handle native libraries transparently?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the research I've done in the past, there are only two ways to get native libraries loaded: modifying `java.library.path` and using `System.loadLibrary` (I feel like most people do this), or using `System.load` with an absolute path.

As you've alluded to, messing with `java.library.path` can be annoying in terms of configuring SBT and Eclipse, and I do not think it's possible to do automatically for an executable jar.

So that leaves `System.load`. In terms of writing your own native libraries, what you can do is:

- Create an SBT task that compiles your native sources (with `javah` and `gcc`), takes the resulting .so files and any .so files it depends on, puts them in a jar (as resources) in the target directory, and adds the path to the jar to `unmanagedJars in Compile`.
- Create a Scala method to load a library. Instead of calling `System.loadLibrary`, it will use `Class.getResourceAsStream` to read the library, `File.createTempFile` to write it somewhere on the filesystem, and `System.load` to load it into the JVM.
- Now instead of calling `System.loadLibrary` as you would before, call `MyClasspathJniLoader.loadLibrary`.

That will work with SBT run, Eclipse, and executable jars without any extra configuration (although I don't know how proguard knows which resources to include).

Now as to third party native libraries that have already been written, some of them like [jblas](http://www.jblas.org) already use this "fat jar" approach. If they expect you to set up `java.library.path` and then they call `System.loadLibrary` when they feel like it, you'll need to do some magic to make that work.

I haven't tried this, but this solution might work:

- Use a similar SBT task to put all of the libraries on their native path into a jar as resources, and put that jar on the clsaspath.
- Create a Scala method that takes a function and a list of library names, creates a temp directory, reads those libraries from the jar's resources into files in the temp directory, adds the temp directory to `java.library.path`, calls the passed in function, and finally reverts the `java.library.path` back to what it was before.
- The first time you call into the native library (when it presumably will statically initialize and make the `System.loadLibrary` call), wrap that particular call in your method with the list of libraries it will load. That way, when it calls `System.loadLibrary`, all of its libraries will be on `java.library.path` and will be loaded successfully.

Obviously this is annoying since you have to manually initialize the third party library before using it, but it seems more feasible to wrap all of the initialization points (your main functions and test initializations) than it does to get all of your tools to set `java.library.path` correctly. And it may be even easier than that if you already have your own layer of abstraction above the third party library, so there's really only one initialization point you have to wrap.

If that seems like a realistic solution, I can add more details about the SBT task or Scala wrapper methods if you're confused.

Comment: could you kindly describe a little detail about "modifying java.library.path and using System.loadLibrary (I feel like most people do this)"?  I want to use java native library with sbt and want to make a jar finally for use, what should I do to include java.library.path, should I change build.sbt, or should I execute certain order for that?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Under Osx, if you have issues loading native libs in `/lib/*.jnilib` during `sbt test`.

`[error] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Fatal execution error, caused by no jniortools in java.library.path`

You can use the following code instead of `System.loadLibrary("jniortools")`.

```
new File("lib").listFiles().map(_.getAbsolutePath).filter(_.endsWith("jniortools.jnilib")).foreach(System.load)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way.

Assume that the native libraries stored in **lib_extra** directory

1. add jna to libraryDependencies:

   > libraryDependencies ++= Seq("net.java.dev.jna" % "jna-platform" %
   >   "4.1.0")
2. add these code to build.sbt:

   > unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "lib_extra"
   >
   > includeFilter in (Compile, unmanagedResourceDirectories):= "*.dll,*.so"