# Add directory to classpath in Build.scala of sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10

At the SBT prompt I am able to add a external directory (which contains linux dynamic libs) to the current compile & test classpath's using the commands -

```
> set fullClasspath in Compile += Attributed.blank(file("/inotify_deps"))
> set fullClasspath in Test += Attributed.blank(file("/inotify_deps"))
```

How can I specify this path in Build.scala itself? I tried -

```
unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "/inotify_deps" },
```

But this does not do the job. How can I modify the fullClasspath variable for both Compile/Test from within Build.scala?

Comment: Are you trying to add dynamic libs like in a native dynamic libs *.dll or *.so? If so you may need to pass `-Djava.library.path` and not to modify the Class Path.

Comment: yes. thanks for the pointer, I found this other well answered question on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761166/integrating-native-system-libraries-with-sbt