# Testing Samza with RocksDB application with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, rocksdb, apache-samza

I would like to run a Samza (using RocksDB KV store) application from SBT. When I do ./sbt "run " I receive the following error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
(snip)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: librocksdbjni-linux64.so was not found inside JAR.
(snip)
```

I assume that since I run with `./run`, sbt runs the classes directly, without assembling a JAR.

The dependencies are set correctly, and I've got the `librocksdbjni-linux64.so` inside RocksDB JAR.

Do I have to create an assembly before running?

How can I test in this case without creating an assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Well, librocksdbjni-linux64.so sounds like a native library, and those usually require a little extra fiddling with things, even if they are inside the path, in order to be recognized and added. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761166/integrating-native-system-libraries-with-sbt).